# How to query dynamodb to retrieve item with prefix `sk` id

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table containing a `pk` which represents the user id and a `sk` which represents an
entityId. There are several entity types and each type has a prefix in the db for the sk. For example:

| pk | sk | someOtherAttribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USER#123 | ENTITYA#456 | someValue |
| USER#123 | ENTITYB#789 | someValue |
| USER#123 | ENTITYC#012 | someValue |
| USER#123 | ENTITYD#023 | someValue |
| USER#123 | ENTITYE#045 | someValue |

Now I need to write a query to retrieve the item with the correct userID and the correct entityId. However
I do not know which entityType the entityId belongs to but I know that it is either `ENTIYB` or `ENTITYC` or `ENTITYD`.

Is it possible to write a query which returns the item with the correct userId and the correct entityId without
knowing the entityType but with the information of a collections of entityTypes? I know that I could write a query for each entityType and then merge the results but I would
like to avoid that.

Comment: Invert your sk? For example: `789#ENTITYB` then you can query for pk=`USER#123` and sk begins with `789#`. Or sk of the form`ENTITY#789#B` and query for pk=`USER#123` and sk begins with `ENTITY#789#`.

Comment: yea that would be a clever approach, however I can not change the existing table and how items are saved there.

Comment: If you cannot change the table at all then you also cannot add a GSI to solve this as you don't appear to have the standalone attribute values available to do it.

Comment: ok I was not precise, I could add a GSI but I can not change how the items are saved in the db

Comment: I'm saying that adding a GSI cannot solve this problem afaik. You don't have the data in an appropriate form (e.g. standalone entity ID attribute) to populate the GSI. I think you're stuck with the query on `USER#123` and then filter the list of returned items.

Comment: so the only solution I have is to query the db 3 times...

Comment: No, it's one query (on pk=`USER#123` and possibly sk begins_with `ENTITY`) and a filter on sk (ends with `#789`) but the filter has to be client-side because I don't think server-side filter-expression support ends_with.

Comment: Well I am afraid that the data will be too big at some point when I get all items for one User so I thought 3 queries are better

Comment: can I combine multiple begins_with? then I could get all `ENTIYB`, `ENITYC` and `ENTITYD` of on user, and then filter the correct id client side

Comment: OK, I see why you would want to filter your query for begins_with ENTITYA/B/C. Filter expressions can use logical operators so try something like query on `pk="USER#123"` and filter expression of `begins_with(sk, "ENTITYA#") or begins_with(sk, "ENTITYB#") or begins_with(sk, "ENTITYC#")`

Comment: thanks  ah and I guess in the key expression this won't work

Comment: hm so apparenlty I can not use filter expression on a sk and key condition expressions can not use `OR`... so I have no options here

Comment: Agree, unfortunately. You're right that the docs say "A filter expression cannot contain partition key or sort key attributes" (wasn't aware of that wrinkle). Personally I'd pursue a table design change if the performance and cost associated with this wasteful query is too high.

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a sort key using "contains", as that would be very expensive to check every sort key within a partition.

The idiomatic solution here would be to create a GSI that contains an ordering of your components that meets your query needs. So in this case, your GSI could be formatted as ${Id}#${EntityType}, which would allow you to query for rows beginning with your id.